# Flutter send and show data between BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to share and show data between **BottomNavigationBarItems**

It is my BottomNavigationBar page:

```
class BottomNavigationBarController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarControllerState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarControllerState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarControllerState
    extends State<BottomNavigationBarController> {
  List<Widget> pages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    pages.add(HomePage(
      key: PageStorageKey('HomePage'),
    ));
    pages.add(MapPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('MapPage'),
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.map), label: "MapPage"),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("iArrived"),
          actions: _currentIndex != 1
              ? <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentIndex++;
                        });
                      })
                ]
              : null),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_currentIndex),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: pages,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I want to send my location from the **MapPage** to the **HomePage**.
There is a function in the **MapPage** that is executed when the place change:

```
void _setLocation(LatLng latlng) {
    setState(() {
      lat = latlng.latitude;
      lng = latlng.longitude;
    });
  }
```

I think I have to call some function like a callback inside ***_setLocation()*** but I don't know how to implement it to show the location on my **HomePage** and have it refresh every time I change it.
Thanks for the help.

If your answer is to use ***[shared_preferences](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value)*** plugin, can you tell me how would you implement it? Because I tried it and it did not work for me.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) plugin for state management:

1. Create a model that store a shared value:

```dart
class LocationModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Location location;

  void updateLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

2. Wrap your root widget with Provider class:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext build) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (_) => LocationModel(),
    child: App(),
  );
}
```

3. When you changing a shared value in a model (you need to get a model from Provider, it depends on concrete implementation). For example:

```dart
onTap() {
  model.updateLocation(newLocation):
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to review the documentation you sent because I did not know the plugin and it is great! Thank you very much! It was very useful!